# Is it possible to integrate Paypal into a non-web application?

Tags: paypal

I have been tasked with integrating a payment system into our application, which is a full screen DirectX stand alone windows executable.  It does not exist in a browser!  Paypal would be ideal for our purposes, but after going through documents on the many various Paypal apis I'm still not quite clear if this is possible.  Basically, I want to be able to have the user make a payment without having to leave the application.  If the application needs to communicate with our own web server, which then handles the communication to paypal, that is not a problem.  If the application needs to communicate with Paypal directly through some sort of REST api, that is also not a problem. If the application needs to display official Paypal logos, also fine.  But having to leave the full screen application and navigate to a web page is a nogo.  Is Paypal still an option?  If not are there alternatives that handles transactions in a large number of countries?

Comment: checkout Paypal API: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_overview